# When and where to use ternary operator?

Tags: operators, ternary-operator

I often read ternary operator(? : ) in books,but I am not clear the best practice of it.
What is the advantages and disadvantages or best practice of it?

Comment: It's shorthand for `if (condition) someValue  else someOtherValue`.  That's all.

Comment: use it when you have two values - one for true, and one for false - rather than doing an `if ... else ...`. It is more compact. Also, in some languages, it is actually an operator and is not truely shorthand for `if ... else ...`

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/ternary-operator-considered-harmful

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's not 100 percent true. Try `const int i = (some condition) ? x : y;`

Comment: @JesseGood: not sure what your point is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Just that my example is not possibe with an if-else statement.

Comment: @JesseGood: Of course it isn't.  You're trying to assign to a constant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sorry, [should think it through next time](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5fdd8d35241054d).

Comment: Python doesn't have a ternary operator.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr see [the FAQ](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator)

Comment: Sam (and others) - I recommend that you read this Meta answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354) which is about "best practice" questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Jesse's example is valid, and another such example is initialization of a reference with a referent chosen by some condition. This can only be expressed by an `if` by embedding that in a function (which can be a lambda). So there is a clear difference in what kind of choice can be used for what.

Comment: @MattDMo yes. There is an equivilent, but there is no specific operator.

Comment: @Alf: I saw Jesse's [code sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5fdd8d35241054d).  Seems like that works because everything derives from a constant, so the compiler can infer the actual value at compile time.  Note that the actual programming language was never specified in the OP.

Answer (score 6):

The ternary operator `? :` represents an `if-then-else` construct, except that it actually returns a value. So instead of:

```
if ( condition )
    x = expression1;
else
    x = expression2;
```

You can write:

```
x = (condition) ? (expression1) : (expression2);
```

In C, C++, Java, etc., you cannot write:

```
x = if (condition) (expression1) else (expression2);
```

Some languages, like Ruby, do allow a form like that, however, since statements in Ruby always return a value, and the value of a block is the value returned by the last statement in a block.

Comment: Would you care to provide the context you have in mind when you say that ":?" represents an `if-then-else`, which (you go on to explain) is different from what it does in C. As far as I know this syntax originates with C.

Comment: He says that it actually returns a value, unlike its `if else` cousin.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: that's an invalid and very misleadeing generalization. he says that "*but* in ... C ... it *actually* returns a value". i do not believe that you didn't understand that.

Comment: See my update to his answer.  Maybe that makes it clearer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the edit. I had worded it a little poorly so it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the operator as

```
int nNum1 = 10, nNum2 = 20, nMax = ( nNum1 > nNum2 ) ? nNum1 : nNum2
```

It is shorthand for simple if-else comparisons, where a variable is assigned based on the result of the comparison.